# How can I add data to dynamic fields when using solr's extract functionality?

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-tika, solr-cell

I'm using a PHP library called solr-php-client (http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) to interface with my Solr server. I can extract data from the document, store it, and search on it, but I can't seem to get it to allow me to add my own data to the parameters for indexing:

```
$aParams = array
(
    "literal.ClassName_ms" => "File",
    "literal.SS_ID_i" => 73,
    "literal.Name_ms" => "OverviewOfBenefits.pdf",
    "literal.title" => "Overview Of Benefits",
    "literal.Created_dt" => "2011-09-19T13:50:30Z",
    "literal.last_modified_dt" => "2011-10-12T19:33:59Z",
    "literal.SS_Stage_ms" => "Live",
    "literal.ClassNameHierarchy_ms" => array("Object","ViewableData","DataObject","File"),
    "literal.id" => "File_73_Live",
    "fmap.content" => "text",
);

try {

    $oResponse = $oSOLR->extract($sFilePath, $aParams);
    $oSOLR->commit();
    $oSOLR->optimize();

}
catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I can query "text" and get results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
 <int name="status">0</int>
 <int name="QTime">0</int>
 <lst name="params">
  <str name="indent">on</str>
  <str name="start">0</str>
  <str name="q">text:Overview</str>
  <str name="rows">10</str>
  <str name="version">2.2</str>
 </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
 <doc>
  <arr name="content_type"><str>application/pdf</str></arr>
  <str name="id">File_73_Live</str>
  <date name="last_modified">2011-02-07T16:21:10Z</date>
 </doc>
</result>
</response>
```

But I can't query any of the dynamic fields, i.e. "SS_Stage_ms":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
 <int name="status">0</int>
 <int name="QTime">0</int>
 <lst name="params">
  <str name="indent">on</str>
  <str name="start">0</str>
  <str name="q">SS_Stage_ms:Live</str>
  <str name="rows">10</str>
  <str name="version">2.2</str>
 </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

Here are the applicable schema definitions:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="false"/>
<dynamicField name="*_ms"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="false"/>
```

Comment: can you mark the dynamic field *_ms with stored true and check whether they are returned with the response.

Comment: The log entry from the Solr server where the add is taking place would also be useful, including the commit message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the schema definitions to store the data so I could see how the fields were being interpreted by Solr:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_ms"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

After doing this, I found that all of the fields were getting switched to lowercase. I found my answer (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler):

> lowernames=true|false - Map all field names to lowercase with underscores. For example, Content-Type would be mapped to content_type.

By default "lowernames" is set to true. I added "lowernames" to the parameters, set it to false, and voila, it worked!